# My 'ASP.Net Dev Server' is having formatting issues

Tags: html, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Using Visual Studio 2008, running a project.. any project it seems. It appears as though any centering is ignored when run through my 'ASP.Net Dev Server' yet once published to any of our IIS servers the centering is fine. I say centering because that seems to be the only problem.

I've seen this question before but the reverse.

example:

I use this DIV tag to center contents:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
Contents...
</div>
```

On the Dev server, no formatting takes placed. Once published it looks as it should.

We have the same problem using VS2010.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Once the page is rendered, this is what the source looks like:

```
<div style="text-align:center">        
    <table width="90%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr style="background-color: #FF3700;">
            <td>
...and so on..
```

Just as I expect. I don't know of any other way to test this stuff. It works the same in IE as it does in FF. As I said, the page renders fine when running from an IIS server but from this dev server.. no go.

I'm not new.. but this makes absolutely NO sense to me. AFAIK, it's the browser's job to render the html & css. Why it renders differently is beyond me. I am going to try a couple more tests.

This might be a case of PEBKAC.. it has something to do with my MASTER page because when I created a page not using it the formatting worked as expected. It doesn't make sens why it would render differently on the dev server tho.. in any case thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked in a browsers developer console to ensure that the styles are indeed not being rendered? That will tell you if it's a CSS or server side issue.

Comment: So what does the HTML look like when you point a browser at your dev server?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the output from the server the div tag is there.